# Batch file to remove string and append new string to text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've been trying to automate the editing of webpack's index.ts file by creating a batch script as follows:

```
ren index.html index.txt

findstr /v 'inline.bundle.js /html' index.txt > index.html

del index.txt

@echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body></html>' >> index.html
```

However, running the batch file will yield this output:

```
PS C:\Users\x> .\batch.bat

C:\Users\x>ren index.html index.txt

C:\Users\x>findstr /v 'inline.bundle.js /html' index.txt  1>index.html
FINDSTR: Cannot open /html'

C:\Users\x>del index.txt
< was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\x>@echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body></html>' >> index.html

PS C:\Users\x>
```

Note that cmd added a '1' to the '>' character in line 2, and a '<' character was typed for no reason after line 3. I've checked the encoding and it's ANSI, so it's not an encoding issue.

Also, copy pasting the lines one by one into cmd or PowerShell does the job just fine. The issue arises when I run the batch file. Any ideas?

**Edit**

Here is the last two lines of my file: *(line break guessed unable to determine for sure from comments)*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I want it to only retain the  with main.bundle.js, but since findstr /v (apparently) only works per line, I've resorted to the above workaround of deleting the last two lines and appending the correct string back.

Comment: Have you tried using a QUOTATION MARK rather than an APOSTROPHE around the string being searched for? " vs. '

Comment: It may help if you provide us with a reasonable snippet of the input file, because it appears, at first glance, that your actual task may be just to replace any instance of `src="inline.bundle.js"` with `src="main.bundle.js"` and that probably should happen regardless of whether the closing `</html>` or even `</script>` tag is on that line.

Comment: @Compo yeah I really should've done that, anyway here it is:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>`

This is the last two lines of code. I want it to only retain the `<script>` with `main.bundle.js`, but since `findstr /v` (apparently) only works per line, I've resorted to the above workaround of deleting the last two lines and appending the correct string back.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ren index.html index.txt    
findstr /v "inline.bundle.js /html" index.txt > index.html    
del index.txt    
@echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body></html>' >> index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. First, cmd thinks that `/html' is a file name to search. Use a QUOTATION MARK around the search string.

Second, `findstr` will search for multiple strings unless you use `/C:`.

```
findstr /v /C:"inline.bundle.js /html" index.txt > index.html
```

For the `echo` line, it could also use QUOTATION MARK, but this will put the QUOTATION MARK characters into the output. To avoid that, the redirection symbols will need to be escaped.

```
@echo ^<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"^>^</script^>^</body^>^</html^> >index.html
```